# Subtraction of functions with BigO

Tags: asymptotics

When trying to assess the Big $O$ of two functions that are added together, we take the max of the two. What happens if there is subtraction instead of addiiton?

for instance: $$f(n) = O(n^3)  $$
$$ \text{and} $$ $$g(n) = O(n^3)$$
then
$$ (f-g)(n)$$

Comment: You want to know if $(f-g)(n)$ is $O(n^3)$ ?

Comment: basically yes, do I still take the max which in this case, they are the same

Comment: If you consider the max of the two it won't be wrong (still $f-g$ will be the same as it). However if you know what exactly are these functions it's better to substract them and bound the result. You'll get something way more accurate.

Comment: What if $f(n) = bigO(n^2)$, would you still take the max of the two, or the min?

Comment: It's the max. If $f(n) = n^2$ and $g(n) = n^3$, then $(f - g)(n) = n^2 - n^3$. However $|n^2 - n^3| \leq |n^3|$ for all sufficiently large $n$, so $(f - g)(n) = O(n^3)$. Note that $(f-g)(n) \neq O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the sign of a function doesn't matter in $O $-notation:

If $f(n)\in O (h(n)) $ then $-f(n)\in O (h(n))$ follows directly from the definition of the $O $-Notation.

For two functions $f (n)\in O (h_1 (n)) $ and $g (n)\in O (h_2 (n))$ you know
$$f(n)+g (n)\in O (\max (h_1 (n), h_2 (n))). $$ where in this case 
$\max (h_1 (n), h_2 (n))=h_1(n)$ means that $h_2 (n)\in O ( h_1 (n))$ respectively $\max (h_1 (n), h_2 (n))=h_2(n)$ means that $h_1 (n)\in O ( h_2 (n))$ .

Therefore, you can follow
$$f (n)-g (n)=f (n)+ (-g (n))\in O (\max (h_1 (n), h_2 (n)))$$
since $-g (n)\in O (h_2 (n))$, too.